# C - Exception thrown: read access violation

Tags: c, string, access-violation

I'm new to programming and I just recently started learning C.

Every week we have "labs" where we have 90 mins to finish the given tasks and so far every week I get the same error "Exception thrown: read access violation." My question is, what does it mean? I can't seem to figure out what it actually means and how to solve it. Every week I spend half of the given time just trying to figure out what's  wrong. I would really appreciate if someone explained to me what to do/what to look for when I get this error.

Once the error was gone after I fixed in my code some passing of a pointer/address (not sure which one but it was wrong). When I fixed that, the error was gone.

Another time the error was gone after I noticed that one of my loops doesn't stop where it should it just went on to very high numbers (no, not forever, I don't know why). When I fixed the loop the error was gone.

I hope it's clear what I'm trying to ask but I will include my current problem but I don't think it's really necessary to look at. Thanks in advance for any help!

This time I tried to write a task at home and once again I got the same error but I haven't yet figured out what is wrong. The task was to:

> Write function:
>
> int find_next_word(const char *string, int startIndex, int *end);
>
> which will search string for the first word, starting at *startIndex*,
>   return the index of its first character. A word is a nonempty sequence
>   of alphanumeric characters, surrounded by other non-alphanumeric
>   characters, beginning or end of the string (use function
>   *is_alphanumeric* to classify characters). Function should also search
>   for a first character after the word (possibly the null terminating
>   character) and store its index in the variable pointed to by *end*.

*is_alphanumeric* is a function from a previous task which I wrote and is included in the code; it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int is_alfanumeric(char c);
int find_next_word(const char* str, int start, int* end);

void main(void)
{
    /********Part 1********/
    puts("********Part 1********");
    char c = (char)getchar();
    if (is_alfanumeric(c))
        printf("%c is a letter or a number\n", c);
    else
        printf("%c is neither a letter nor a number\n", c);

    /********Part 2********/
    puts("********Part 2********\n");
    char str[] = "  ThhHhis is MmmMy,\t tTesttt string \t \n";
    printf("Original string:\n[%s]\n", str);
    int end;
    int start = find_next_word(str, 0, &end);
    printf("First word start: %d, end: %d\n", start, end);
    start = find_next_word(str, end, &end);
    printf("Second word start: %d, end: %d\n", start, end);
    system("pause");
}

int is_alfanumeric(char c) {
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' || c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
int find_next_word(const char* str, int start, int* end) {
    int i = start;
    for (; is_alfanumeric(str[i]); i++);
    for (; !is_alfanumeric(str[i]) && str[i] != '\0'; i++);
    return i;
    for (; is_alfanumeric(str[i]); i++);
    *end = i;
}
```

Comment: Aside: `char c = (char)getchar();` ==> `int c = getchar();`. Go with the types provided, follow that through your own functions. Very few (any?) library functions either take or return the `char` type. Also note that `'a'` is of type `int`.

Comment: Actually everything that's in main is prewritten by our professor.... we only have to write the functions. But I was actually wondering why it is written the way it is...

Comment: Get a new professor, if he writes `void main(void)` which includes `system("pause");`

Comment: yeah easy to say :P
but the system("pause"); was added by me so the window doesn't close... I haven't figured out yet how to do it differently, as I said, I'm green

Comment: Use `getchar()` in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running past yourself with your loops. In your first loop, you run straight to the end
of the char array. (Remmember, C doesn't have "strings", it has character arrays.) Then, in your
second loop, you get an access violation because you're trying to index past the end of the array. Try this:

```
int find_next_word(const char *str, int start, int *end) {
    int i = start;
    int r = 0;

    for (; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {

        /* You want the FIRST character that satisfies the conditions */
        if (is_alfanumeric(str[i]) {
            r = i;
            break;
        }          
    }

    if (r > start) {

        /* If r is greater than start, you know you found a character
           before the end of the array, so now you can increment
           your cursor until you find a non-alfanumeric character,
           or you run out of array. */

        for (; !is_alfanumeric(str[i]); i++);
    }
    *end = i;
    return r;
}
```

Comment: for (; is_alfanumeric(str[i]); i++);
you mean this loop? Correct me if I'm wrong but this loop is supposed to go until it hits a non alphabet/number character meaning a space, why do you say it goes until the end of the array? And the thing about your suggestion is that I think (obv I might be wrong) but think about what if "start" is lets say "5". Then you will be in middle of "ThhHhis" and you will return the index of a character in the middle of "ThhHhis" and not "return the index of its first character" as the task says.

Comment: That's why with my first loop (my hope is to) see if it is already in middle of a word, if it is go past it. Then with the second loop go past 'space' so then I finally have my first word from the beginning.

Comment: Yes, the problem statement is ambiguous wrt starting in the middle of a word; you may have to adjust the code for that interpretation. However, note that you never set the value of end because you're returning before you do. And, if there are no spaces, your first loop will end on the null terminator.

Comment: Hmm so you mean that nothing is done after "return i"?

Comment: I guess it isn't. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, no other code is executed after a return statement.